# Access etcd metrics for Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, etcd

I have set up a v1.13 Kubernetes cluster using Kube spray.
Our etcd is running as docker containers outside the K8s cluster. If I check the etcd certificates, I can see each etcd has its own ca, client cert and key.

If I want to scrape the /metrics endpoints of these etcd conatiners for Prometheus, which certificates to use for the HTTPS endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

I am not yet sure, if this is the most secured way or not.
But I took the ca.pem, cert and key that one of the etcd uses.

I created a Kubernetes secret object out of the three:

```
kubectl create secret generic etcd-metrics -n monitoring --from-file=etcd-secrets/
```

Then I added the secrets as configmaps in Prometheus config and below as my scrape

```
targets:
- job_name: etcd
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  static_configs:
 - targets:
   - 172.xxxxx:2379
   - 172.xxxxx:2379
   - 172.xxxxx:2379
 tls_config:
  ca_file: /etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem
  cert_file: /etc/ssl/etcd/etcd-node.pem
  key_file: /etc/ssl/etcd/etcd-key.pem
  insecure_skip_verify: false
```

Comment: @Tibebes. M This looks really promising. I tried to launch a pod in our cluster, but it can't resolve the etcd hosts. When I list the pods, the etcd container does not show up. I can only find it when performing a `docker ps` on the host.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you asked, I had great success pushing that authentication down onto the actual machine by using [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) running in a sidecar container listening on [etcd's prometheus port :9379](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations) and then you can just point prometheus at `http://${etcd_hostname}:9379/metrics` without having to deal with authentication for those metrics endpoints.

I don't have the `socat` invocation in front of me, but something like:

```
socat tc4-listen:9379,reuseaddr,fork \
   openssl:127.0.0.1:2379,capath=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/cacert.crt,key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key,cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt
```