# Accessing etcd metrics a pod

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, etcd

I'm trying to launch a prometheus pod in order to scrape the etcd metrics from within our kubernetes cluster.

I was trying to reproduce the solution proposed here: [Access etcd metrics for Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129368/access-etcd-metrics-for-prometheus)

Unfortunately, the etcd containers seem to be unavailable from the cluster.

```
# nc -vz etcd1 2379
nc: getaddrinfo for host "etcd1" port 2379: Name or service not known
```

In a way, this seems logical since no etcd container appear in the cluster:
`kubectl get pods -A | grep -i etcd` does not return anything.

However, when I connect onto the machine hosting the master nodes, I can find the containers using the `docker ps` command.

The cluster has been deployed using Kubespray.

Do you know if there is a way to reach the etcd containers from the cluster pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh… the etcd container is configured with the host network. Therefore, the metrics endpoint is directly accessible on the node.